# How to use jQuery's .each function to parse parent elements and their children

Tags: jquery

I'd eventually build an associative array with the `.image` `class` number and the `.qty` in this HTML, but first, I need to parse it out with the elusive jQuery `.each` function.

```
<div class="image 324">
    <div class="options">
        <p>Sizes</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty1" class="qty" value=""> 8x10</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty2" class="qty" value="1">11x14</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty3" class="qty" value="">16x20</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image 231">
    <div class="options">
        <p>Sizes</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty4" class="qty" value="2"> 8x10</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty5" class="qty" value="">11x14</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty6" class="qty" value="1">16x20</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
 $('.image').each(function(index) {
    console.log( index+": "+$(this).attr('class') );
    $('.qty').each(function(index) {
      console.log( index+': '+$(this).val() );
    });
  });
});
 </script>
```

The desired result in this first step would be:

```
0: image 324
0: 
1: 1
2:
1: image 231
0: 2
1:
2: 1
```

Instead it is "looping" through all six of the `.qty` for each `.image` like:

```
0: image 324
0: 
1: 1
2: 
3: 2
4: 
5: 1
1: image 231
0: 
1: 1
2: 
3: 2
4: 
5: 1
```

In the dozens of examples I've looked at, this is the closest I could get. I'm missing something fundamental about `.each` but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The `$('.qty')` selector will get *all* elements with that class, regardless of the parent element(s).

Use the current `.image` reference to `find` all the `.qty` elements *within* that parent.

Try the example below, there is only 1 line to change. (side note, I like to use `prop` over `attr`, but keep whichever you prefer)

```js
$(function() {
 $('.image').each(function(index) {
    console.log( index+": "+$(this).prop('class') );
    $(this).find('.qty').each(function(index) {      // CHANGE THIS LINE
      console.log( index+': '+$(this).val() );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image 324">
    <div class="options">
        <p>Sizes</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty1" class="qty" value=""> 8x10</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty2" class="qty" value="1">11x14</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty3" class="qty" value="">16x20</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image 231">
    <div class="options">
        <p>Sizes</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty4" class="qty" value="2"> 8x10</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty5" class="qty" value="">11x14</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="qty6" class="qty" value="1">16x20</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! `.find`, the magic sauce. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, how do you get color syntax for your Stackoverflow code samples?

Comment: For that runnable example, on the editor tool bar, use the `<>` icon to create a `code snippet` where there are 3 sections for HTML, Javascript, and CSS. I did not use the CSS section in that example. It is possible to test run from that interface while editing too. There are options for some external libs (such as jQuery) in the left side of the editor. More info about the `code snippet` and be [found here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/7644018).